# Управление контролами из ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf

Простите за глупый вопрос, но что я делаю не так?

Есть форма WPF, у нее ViewModel, настроен binding на свойства, в set'тере свойств событие оповещения вызывается выше, в унаследованных методах (использую GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase).

```
public abstract class QuestionnairesBaseViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // ...
    protected void SetField<T>(ref T field, T value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return;               
            field = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
        catch { field = default(T); }
    }
    // ...
}

public class FormLViewModel : QuestionnairesBaseViewModel, IQuestionnaireViewModel, IDataErrorInfo
{
    // ...
    private string _birthPlace;
    public string BirthPlace
    {
        get => _birthPlace;
        set => SetField(ref _birthPlace, value);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Если я устанавливаю  значение свойства в конструкторе VM, то окно открывается и соответствующий контрол отображает установленное значение.

Но если я уже в процессе работы устанавливаю в одном из методов VM значение свойства - то оно устанавливается (отладчиком проверял), событие вызывается, но контрол в окне свой вид не меняет и измененное значение не отображает.

Это же базовый режим работы в модели MVVM - обработку данных делать во VM. Но из-за этого мне уже не раз приходилось устанавливать значения контролов прямо в файле присоединенного кода формы. Что удивительно - при этом все прекрасно сразу отображается и состояние VM тоже меняется. Но очень, мягко говоря, "так себе"...

Comment: P.S. Естественно, binding установлен в режиме TwoWay

Comment: Судя по коду вы потеряли `propertyName`

Comment: RaisePropertyName() его не требует в обязательном порядке. У него есть значение по умолчанию (из метаданных):        //
        // Параметры:
        //   propertyName:
        //     (optional) The name of the property that changed.
        //
        // Примечания.
        //     If the propertyName parameter does not correspond to an existing property on
        //     the current class, an exception is thrown in DEBUG configuration only.
        public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null);

Comment: У вас по-видимому какая-то путаница с вызовом `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Если вы используете фреймворк с готовой к применению `ViewModelBase`, то зачем еще пишите сами `QuestionnairesBaseViewModel`?

Comment: Я использую QuestionnairesBaseViewModel для инкапсуляции ряда общих членов группы однотипных VM

Comment: @АндрейКутасевич, `[CallerMemberName]` не полезет выше по стеку, поэтому тут вы просто обязаны передать название свойства

Comment: Мой вам совет, выбросьте нафиг GalaSoft.MvvmLight. и пишите нормально сами, все эти фрейморки только усложняют все дело, и вы начинаете путаться, то ли это вы сами неправильно что-то написали, то ли неправильно применили фичу зашитую в этот фрейморк. Короче, скрипач не нужен.

Comment: @АндрейNOP его передавать прямо строкой в метод ' protected void SetField<T>(ref T field, T value) ' ? Или как-то иначе можно его получить в моем коде?

Comment: Да, вам надо переписать сигнатуру метода так: `SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")` и потом передавать явно: `RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);`

Comment: В вашем фреймворке, кстати, есть уже такой же готовый метод: https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/bb9436e28a9916d81c287b2efa6ed66600e74c4e/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/ViewModelBase.cs#L357 Почему не используете его?

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо. Я решил использовать метод с сигнатурой: protected bool Set<T>(string propertyName, ref T field, T newValue = default, bool broadcast = false); вместо моего SetField